# What's an Efficient Alternative to LIMIT?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sqlperformance

My question basically is: How can I tell my database to do a seq scan and STOP after the first match to my WHERE condition?

Assuming I want to find the first event of a certain type, I could write the following query:

```
select *
from installs
where country = 'China' 
order by install_date
limit 1
```

The problem here is that according to order of operations the engine would scan all the table and generate a dataset that matches my filter, then sort this dataset (with an immense cost), and then return only the first row.

I could of course filter by specific dates, but let's assume I don't know the period to filter by - how can I optimize this type of query in Amazon Redshift (something in the where clause maybe)?

Comment: If you don't have a way to create an index on `install_date` (or arrange that some other field such as the record id follows the same ordering), there is not much you can do. The database will have to retrieve and sort all matching records.

Comment: you could use install_date as the sortkey for the table.

Comment: How should the database know which `install_date` is the smallest unless it looks at all of them?

Comment: You may be able to do what you want using a sort key:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html.

Comment: Is this an example of the actual queries that you're trying to do? If yes, then Redshift may not be the appropriate database for you. If you have less than, say 100,000,000 rows then you'll probably find that a standard Postgres database will be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: @kdgregory it's an actual query (changed field and table names obviously), though not a very frequent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift's general strategy is to do a lot of scanning, but parallelize it. Any case that involves getting a single row is not going to be ideal. That said, you can do four things:

**1. Reduce scanning, to a point**

If country will always be the field filtered on, set the sortkey for the table to a compound sortkey on country first.

**2. Eliminate the need for sorting**

A more efficient way to do `ORDER BY x LIMIT 1` is often MAX.

Then try

```
SELECT *
FROM installs
WHERE pk = (
  SELECT MAX(pk)  -- or install_date, if install date is unique
  FROM installs
  WHERE country = 'China'
)
```

**3. Tailor the selected columns between row oriented and columnar**

Asking a columnar database like Redshift to select * incurs costs for each column. Try selecting only the columns you need.

**4. Add more nodes, so each node does less scanning**

(Make sure the data is not set to distribution style all)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I actully didn't select * in my query, I will edit it in the post. Regarding max aggregate function - it does not require sorting as a pre-condition anyway?

Comment: No. If I give you a list, like [8,2,13,4,9,1,7], would you have to sort the whole thing just to find the max? No, you just pass through it once, remembering the single highest value and forgetting the rest

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `ORDER BY`, then it can work efficiently.

The requirement to sort the results means it needs to examine all rows where the country is China, which is not efficient for returning one item.

The `where country = 'China'` clause is efficient if `SORTKEY = country` since it can skip over any storage blocks that do not contain the desired value. This will be highly efficient if there are very relatively few rows that match.

If you are frequently querying for one-row results, then it might be worth **storing such information in a separate table for faster lookup**. The value could be calculated every day, or every hour, as necessary.

Comment: But if you remove the `order by` the result is not guaranteed to return the first event, it could be any event that matches the where clause.

Comment: Yes. But it _would_ be efficient! :)